# How to add values from one column to timestamp column as days?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, filter, timestamp

I have a table df:

```
date                     day       
2021-07-25                1 
2021-07-29                1 
2021-07-30                1
```

I want to filter it this way:

```
df[df['device_install_date'] + df['lifetime'] < '2021-07-27']
```

But it brings error:

```
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str
```

How can I do that? values in day column should add as days to date. `Column day has type pandas.core.series.Series`

Answer (score 0):

In order to do this you have to make sure your using the right data types. In you example I'm assuming the date column is a datetime so in order to increment the date column by days you need to use a time delta then compare the date to a date like so.

```
df = pd.DataFrame([
    {'date':'2021-07-25','days':1},
    {'date':'2021-07-29','days':1},
    {'date':'2021-07-30','days':1}
])

df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df['days'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['days'],unit='D')
query = df[(df['date']+df['days']).dt.date<pd.to_datetime('2021-07-27').date()]
print(query)
```